# How to deduce subtype of a class from a base pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base class (Notification) and two subclasses (WebNotification and DesktopNotification). I receive WebNotifications and DesktopNotifications from an external source and than I pass them along as Notification pointers to an GUI entity that's supposed to do different things based on the type of notification.
How can I deduce the subtype based on a Notification* ?

I know adding an enum with the type to the Notification class would work but it doesn't seem like an elegant solution.

Do I have any alternatives?

Comment: You're approaching this the wrong way. Consuming code isn't supposed to change its behavior based on what is passed in, it's the thing that is passed in which changes its behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple alternatives are possible.

First of all specialized behavior should be part of the class, not part of the client. This means that you should avoid dynamically check the type of class unless you are really forced to.

This is usually achieved through polymorphism:

```
class Notification {
public:
  virtual void render(UI* ui) = 0;
};

class WebNotification : public Notification {
public:
  void render(UI* ui) override {
    ....
  }
};
```

In some circumstances this is not enough so you can choose to tag your classes, for example

```
class Notification {
public:
  enum class Type {
    WEB,
    DESKTOP
  };

private:
  Type type;

protected:
  Notification(Type type) : type(type) { }

public:
  Type getType() const { return type; }
};

class WebNotification : public Notification {
public:
  WebNotification() : Notification(Notification::Type::WEB) { }
};

...
Notification* notification = ...
if (notification->getType() == Notification::Type::WEB)
  ...
```

or let the compiler tag them for you, but you must enable RTTI and some times this is not desiderable:

```
if (dynamic_cast<WebNotification*>(notification) != null) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Just remember that `dynamic_cast` is very slow and if performance is an issue in any way the slowness will be quite noticeable.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy: Indeed I specified that using RTTI is not always desiderable. But slowness is a relative term, it doesn't mean anything if you don't compare it to anything. A `dynamic_cast` could be considered slow as `virtual` functions are considered slow compared to statically bound but if this is meant to be used in a UI context it sounds really irrelevant. From this point of view then you should drop using polymorphism and use CRTP pattern because virtual invocations are slow.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic casting, ie.

```
Notification* notification;

WebNotification* web_notification = dynamic_cast<WebNotification*>(notification);

    if ( web_notification != NULL ) {
    // this is a web notification;
}

DesktopNotification* dt_notification = dynamic_cast<DesktopNotification*>(notification);
if ( dt_notification != NULL ) {
    // this is a desktop notificaiton
}
```